# combine three tables and count a specific value with mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have the following mySQL table structure:

```
Table 'company'         Table 'serial'                   Table 'product'
+----+--------------+   +-------------------+--------+   +-----+---------+
| id | name         |   | serial            |cid     |   | nr  | name    |
+----+--------------+   +-------------------+--------+   +-----+---------+
|  1 | One Inc.     |   | 100A000001        |      1 |   | 100 | Phone   |
|  2 | Two Corp.    |   | 100A000002        |      1 |   | 101 | Ball    |
|  3 | Three Corp.  |   | 102A000003        |      1 |   | 102 | Egg     |
|  4 | Four Inc.    |   | 103A000004        |      2 |   | 103 | Box     |
|  5 | Five Inc.    |   | 103A000005        |      3 |   | 104 | Cable   |
+----+--------------+   | 101A000006        |      4 |   +-----+---------+
                        | 102A000007        |      4 |
                        | 103A000011        |      5 |
                        | 103A000010        |      5 |
                        | 104A000007        |      5 |
                        | 104A000008        |      5 |
                        | 103A000009        |      5 |
                        +-------------------+--------+
```

A short Description how they work together:

1. **cid** in table **'serial'** is the **company id** from table **'company'**
2. **nr** in table **'product'** defines how the first three digits of a serial have to be for the desired product.

What I need to do is an Output like this:

```
+-------------+--------------------------------------+
| Customer    | Products                             |
+-------------+--------------------------------------+
| One Inc.    | Phone (2), Egg (1)                   |
+-------------+--------------------------------------+
| Two Corp.   | Box (1)                              |
+-------------+--------------------------------------+
| Three Corp. | Box (1)                              |
+-------------+--------------------------------------+
| Four Inc.   | Phone (1), Ball (1)                  |
+-------------+--------------------------------------+
| Five Inc.   | Box (3), Cable (2)                   |
+-------------+--------------------------------------+
```

But i don't know how to write the query!

My solution at the moment is the following query:

```
SELECT
    c.name,
    s.serial
FROM
    company c
INNER JOIN
    serial s
ON
    c.id = s.cid
ORDER BY
    c.name DESC
```

this generates an output like this:

```
+-------------+--------------+ 
| Customer    | Serial       |
+-------------+--------------+ 
| One Inc.    | 100A000001   |
| One Inc.    | 100A000002   |
| One Inc.    | 102A000003   |
| Two Corp.   | 103A000004   |
| Three Corp. | 103A000005   |
| Four Inc.   | 101A000006   |
| Four Inc.   | 102A000007   |
| Five Inc.   | 103A000011   |
| Five Inc.   | 103A000010   |
| Five Inc.   | 104A000007   |
| Five Inc.   | 104A000008   |
| Five Inc.   | 103A000009   |
+-------------+--------------+
```

At the moment I'm using this output and with PHP I'm generating the desired output, but it would be great to do it without much PHP.

So what I'm asking for is:
How can I solve this with a nice mySQL query, to get an output like described above?

Comment: If you are able to do so, you should really split the Serial column up so that it has an FK to the Product table, and then the actual Serial column is just something like "A000001". As it is now, it's a partially derived field.  This will make it much more queryable for you. Also, a FK is a strong relationship. This can be used to ensure data integrity. Otherwise, someone could put something like "ABCA000001", and you wouldn't have a good way to realize that "ABC" isn't a product

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT Customer, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(pname, ' (', pcount, ')')) Products
FROM (
    SELECT
        c.name Customer,
        p.name pname,
        COUNT(*) pcount
    FROM
        company c
    INNER JOIN
        serial s
    ON
        c.id = s.cid
    INNER JOIN
        product p
    ON p.nr = LEFT(s.serial, 3)
    GROUP BY Customer, pname) x
GROUP BY Customer
ORDER BY
    Customer DESC
```

Comment: Really great @Barmar! Is it possible to place a blank after the ,? At the Moment I get results like: Ball,Phone,Egg but I would like to have Ball, Phone, Egg. Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Of course. Use the `SEPARATOR` option in `GROUP_CONCAT`. Can't you read the documentation, instead of having everything spoon fed to you? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Comment: Yes of course, i can read the documentation. :) Before you're comment i didn't know where to search for more options. Thanks again Barmar.

Comment: I know you didn't know about it before my answer. But once I posted the answer, wouldn't the first place to look be the documentation of `GROUP_CONCAT`, to see if you can change how it connects things?

Comment: Hello Barmar, i would like to extend this query with two more tables. I tried a lot, but i didn't not know where to place another Select in this query. Could you give me some hints pls? Or should I create another question?